# Working of Raw Sockets in the Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver, raw-sockets

I'm working on integrating the traffic control layer of the linux kernel to a custom user-level network stack. I'm using raw sockets to do the same. My question is if we use raw sockets with `AF_PACKET`, `RAW_SOCK`, and `IPPROTO_RAW`, will the dev_queue_xmit (the function which is the starting point of the Queueing layer as far as I've read) be called? Or does the sockets interface directly call the network card driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `SOCK_RAW` indicates that the userspace program should receive the L2 (link-layer) header in the message.
- `IPPROTO_RAW` applies the same for the L3 (IP) header.

A userspace program sets `SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW` to manually parse or/and compose protocol headers of a packet. It guarantees that the kernel doesn't modify the corresponding layer header on the way to/from the userspace. The raw socket doesn't change the way the packet gets received or transmitted - those are queued as usual. From the network driver perspective, it doesn't matter who set the headers - the userspace (raw sockets) or the kernel (e.g., SOCK_DGRAM).

Keep in mind that getting raw packets requires `CAP_NET_RAW` capability - usually, the program needs to run with superuser privileges.

Comment: "The raw socket doesn't change the way the packet gets received or transmitted" so packets don't still go through the kernel, context switches etc, just not modified within it?